# Mysql phpmyadmin ST_Distance_Sphere

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to calculate the distance between 2 points using ST_Distance_Sphere

For some reason i am getting inconsistent results in query's which in essence should be the same (as far as i can see)
What am i missing? Shouldn't both query's give me 100.56111825131626

When doing the following query i get: 159.40634880349305

```
select ST_Distance_Sphere(point(52.103472892, 6.312514255),point(52.377779678, 4.905166810))  / 1000
```

When doing:

```
set @lat1 = 52.103472892;
set @lon1 = 6.312514255;
set @lat2 = 52.377779678;
set @lon2 = 4.905166810;
SET @pt1 = point(@lon1, @lat1);
SET @pt2 = point(@lon2, @lat2);
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(@pt1, @pt2)/1000
```

This is the result:

100.56111825131626

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad. Needed to input longitude first then latitude. Did the it in the wrong order.